# Flutter - How to sort a list of DateTime objects according to week ranges

Tags: flutter, sorting, datetime

I have a list of dateTime objects that I would like to sort according to the week ranges of the corresponding year.

How can I determine the week range (start date & end date) for each DateTime object?

Please find attached a screenshot that I have added to showcase what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: maby week number is enough?
https://pub.dev/packages/week_of_year

Comment: Thank you @Paweł. This helped a lot! I got the dates filtered by week ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Without sharing actual code it's hard to pinpoint, but as a suggestion, I suggest taking mod of those dates based on by converting millisecondsSinceEpoch value.